# Spring Data Solr - Multi Core Support

Tags: spring, spring-boot, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

With latest Spring Data Solr `3.0.9-RELEASE` don't we have support fo multicore? `@EnableSolrRepositories(multicoreSupport=true)` or `SolrTemplate.setSolrCore()` ? We are upgrading Spring-Data-Solr from 2.1.13-RELEASE to 3.0.9-RELEASE and seeing compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like multicoreSupport has been removed as per this bug.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-372

and this commit shows it has been removed

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/commit/68464c9401dcfc5bfb34fe6c2f92f621f5df38b8#diff-52a61f95638e45fbc1b02680a1a0004e

Comment: is this still disabled?

Comment: looks like yes. the latest does not contain the attribute